# If $X$ is a Polish space, how do we find an equivalent metric under which $X$ is a totally bounded?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

According to Stroock and Varadhan, If $X$ is a Polish space, then one can choose an equivalent metric under which the space is totally bounded (see Stroock and Varadhan - Multidimensional diffusion processes pg 10).

[image]

How do I find such a metric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the first paragraph after the *Remark* at the top of page $9$:

> Since $X$ is a separable metric space, by Tychonoff’s embedding theorem, $X$ is homeomorphic to a subset of a compact metric space. Thus $X$ admits an equivalent metric $\rho$ with respect to which it is totally bounded.

I would appeal instead to the [Urysohn metrization theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UrysohnsMetrizationTheorem.html), but either way you get $X$ homeomorphic to a subset of the Hilbert cube, which is a compact metric space.

Now you just need to know that total boundedness is hereditary.

> **Proof.** Suppose that $\langle Y,d\rangle$ is totally bounded, and let $X$ be a subspace of $Y$; by a minor abuse of notation I’ll use $d$ for the metric on $X$ as well. Fix $\epsilon>0$; there is a finite $F\subseteq Y$ such that $Y=\bigcup_{y\in F}B\left(y,\frac{\epsilon}2\right)$. Let
>
> $$F_0=\left\{y\in F:B\left(y,\frac{\epsilon}2\right)\cap X\ne\varnothing\right\}\;,$$
>
> and for each $y\in F_0$ choose $x_y\in B\left(y,\frac{\epsilon}2\right)\cap Y$. Let $F_1=\{x_y:y\in F_0\}$; clearly $F_1$ is a finite subset of $X$. Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary. There is a $y\in F$ such that $d(x,y)<\frac{\epsilon}2$, and an application of the triangle inequality shows that $d(x,x_y)<\epsilon$. Thus, $X=\bigcup_{x\in F_1}B(x,\epsilon)$, and $X$ is therefore totally bounded. $\dashv$

In particular, the original $X$ is homeomorphic to a totally bounded metric space, so it admits a totally bounded metric.